# Converting short colorVal = CellStyle.getBottomBorderColor () to RGB value while using Apache POI Java library

Tags: itext, apache-poi

I am reading Excel sheet using Apache POI and writing it to a PDF using iText library.This has been achieved successfully but I am getting default black border for every cell that I write to PDF. So I need to get the cell border color using Apache POI which can be achieved using CellStyle class method getBottomBorderColor() which returns a short value.However I need a way to convert this value to RGB value so that while writing cell to PDF I can apply that RGB color value to the cell border.

Comment: If kind of `Excel` workbook is a `*.xlsx` workbook, then there is [XSSFCellStyle.getBottomBorderXSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#getBottomBorderXSSFColor--) and the `XSSFColor` has [XSSFColor.getRGB](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFColor.html#getRGB--).

Comment: that color is an index not a color itself .. have a look at [`org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColor.fromInt()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/IndexedColors.html). I haven't tested it, but I guess you could use that index to find the color from the [ICV table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd773056(v=office.12).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The `short` value from [CellStyle.getBottomBorderColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellStyle.html#getBottomBorderColor--) is an index of the color in the color palette of the workbook. This is an olld approach for storing colors from the old binary `*.xls` `Excel` format. So in `apache poi` there is only [HSSFPalette](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFPalette.html) which only should be used in `HSSF` and not more be used in `XSSF`.

In newer `*.xlsx` `Excel` formats, the color will either be stored directly as hex value or as reference to a theme color. So for `XSSF` there is [XSSFCellStyle.getBottomBorderXSSFColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFCellStyle.html#getBottomBorderXSSFColor--) to get that color directly and not via index.

So unfortunately we have to differ both aproaches dependent on the kind of `Excel` workbook.

Example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.util.HSSFColor;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

class ExcelCellBorderColor{

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelCellBorderColor.xlsx"));
  //Workbook wb  = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("ExcelCellBorderColor.xls"));

  String strrgb;

  Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
  for (Row row : sheet) {
   for (Cell cell : row) {
    CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
    if (style instanceof XSSFCellStyle) {
     XSSFColor xssfcolor = ((XSSFCellStyle)style).getBottomBorderXSSFColor();
     if (xssfcolor != null) {
      byte[] brgb = xssfcolor .getRGB();
      strrgb = "R:"+String.format("%02X", brgb[0])+",G:"+String.format("%02X", brgb[1])+",B:"+String.format("%02X", brgb[2]);

System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getAddress() + " has border bottom color: " + strrgb);

     } 
    } else if (style instanceof HSSFCellStyle) {
     short colorindex = ((HSSFCellStyle)style).getBottomBorderColor();
     HSSFPalette palette = ((HSSFWorkbook)wb).getCustomPalette();
     HSSFColor hssfcolor = palette.getColor(colorindex);
     if (hssfcolor  != null) {
      short[] srgb = hssfcolor.getTriplet();
      strrgb = "R:"+String.format("%02X", srgb[0])+",G:"+String.format("%02X", srgb[1])+",B:"+String.format("%02X", srgb[2]);

System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getAddress() + " has border bottom color index: " + colorindex + ". This is " + strrgb);

     } 
    }
   }
  }

  wb.close();

 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can archive this by using this color class

```
 CTScRgbColor scrgb = (CTScRgbColor)ch;
    int r = scrgb.getR();
    int g = scrgb.getG();
    int b = scrgb.getB();
       color = new Color(255 * r / 100000, 255 * g / 100000, 255 * b / 100000);
```

Comment: can you let me know what is ch here?